# InstallShield, .msi, custom action and global variables

Tags: windows-installer, global-variables, installshield

I want to implement global variable in InstallShield, basic msi project (2011). I know that according to manual engine is being initialized during start of every custom action so global variables are initialized too. Currently I use MsiSetProperty and MsiGetProperty in order to pass values between custom actions calls (information about success of installation / some data gathered from configuration files etc). is there some faster way of passing these values ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties are the correct way to pass values between custom actions. Note, however, that deferred custom actions are limited in that sense, and the only general purpose property they can access is [CustomActionData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w2fhwzz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (each CA gets its own instance).